# Toda função precisa um return ao final de sua execução?

Tags: python, funções

Bom dia a todos, estou começando meus estudos em python e durante a programação de uma função que vai na planilha e transfere os valores para um dicionário me surgiu uma dúvida: Todas as funções necessitam de um retorno?

No meu caso o dicionário foi iniciado na função **init** sendo assim eu vou querer o resultado após o dicionário ser preenchido com todos materiais de cada setor.

vou deixar o exemplo do código caso eu não tenha conseguido ser claro.

```
class ProdutoPai(object):

def __init__(self, quantidade):
    self.quantidade = quantidade
    self.materiais = {}
    self.chaves = ["Codigo", "Descrição", "Quantidade", "Unidade", "Preço"]

def setor(self):        """
    Essa função acrescenta a self.materiais os materiais usado no DAC para fabricação do modulo base

    :return: None
    """
    wb = load_workbook(self.url)
    ws = wb["setor"]
    linhas = ws.max_row
    prod = self.materiais["produto 1"] = {}

    for linha in range(1, linhas + 1):
       prod[ws["A{}".format(linha)].value] = {self.chaves[0]: ws["A{}".format(linha)].value,
                                             self.chaves[1]: ws["B{}".format(linha)].value,
                                             self.chaves[2]: (ws["D{}".format(linha)].value * self.quantidade),
                                             self.chaves[3]: ws["C{}".format(linha)].value,
                                             self.chaves[4]: (ws["F{}".format(linha)].value *
                                                              (ws["D{}".format(linha)].value * self.quantidade))}
```

Comment: Necessário não é, depende do que vc precisa. Quem chamar a função vai precisar do resultado dela?

Comment: Nesse caso não apenas preciso que altere o valor de self.materiais, a ideia seria retornar ao final de todo processo de alteração.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resposta depende um pouco do que você quer dizer com "necessitar um retorno".

Se você está perguntando se Python *sempre retorna algum valor de uma função*, a resposta é **sim**. Todas as funções em Python retornam algum valor, ainda que este valor seja o valor nulo (`None`).

Se você está perguntando se Python *obriga você, programador, a retornar algum valor de uma função*, a resposta é **não**. Não é necessário adicionar um valor de retorno explícito; na realidade, se você não adicionar a linha final com `return algum_valor`, o Python implicitamente irá retornar `None`.

Se você está perguntando se *faz sentido criar uma função que não retorna algum valor*, a resposta é **depende do que você quer fazer**. Em muitos casos, estamos interessados em algum "efeito colateral" produzido ao chamarmos uma função, como modificar um objeto mutável ou salvar um arquivo em disco. O próprio Python apresenta esse comportamento na biblioteca padrão: a função `print` retorna `None`, porque estamos interessados no seu "efeito colateral" (mostrar texto na tela), e não no que ela retorna.

Esse é o caso do seu método `setor`, que modifica o dicionário (objeto mutável) `self.materiais` diretamente. Como sua classe mantém uma referência a esse dicionário, não há necessidade explícita de retorná-lo. Quando falamos de classes - objetos cujo estado pode ser acessado e modificado durante a execução do código - isto é algo bastante comum.

Dito tudo isso, vale mencionar que, caso você tenha muitas funções com efeitos colaterais, pode dificultar que você entenda a lógica do seu próprio programa. Então por mais que seja possível, por exemplo, modificar um dicionário internamente em uma função sem retorná-lo, pode ser mais simples para você, programador, entender e testar seu próprio código se a função criar um novo dicionário e retorná-lo.

Comment: Faccioni entendi perfeitamente, realmente se eu manter dessa forma em futuras modificações e manutenção seria complexo para mim ou para alguém que fosse utilizar o código depois, muito obrigado pela resposta

Answer (score 0):

Não necessariamente, somente se você precisa que a função retorne algo, como por exemplo:

```
def printMessage():
    print("mensagem")
```

Nesse caso não a necessidade de retorno